# Is software-collection-library free to use in enterprise and with artifactory?

Tags: python, artifactory

I have a question about the use of SCL (https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/).

1. Is SCL free to be used in enterprises for python27 or is there any sort legal issue with that.
2. Is there a way to mirror the SCL components in artifactory ?

Answer (score 1):

The Python License is very permissible and allows free use  and distrubute as modified even commercially.

https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/license/